# query mysql always return duplicate result

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have this query with mysql:

```
SELECT asistencia.codAsistencia, asistencia.fecha, bonos.codBono, asistencia.estado, 
contratan.activo, contratan.codContrato, contratan.tiempoRestanteBono, asistencia.mensaje, users.nombre 
FROM asistencia, users, bonos, contratan 
WHERE asistencia.usuario = users.id 
AND contratan.bono = bonos.codBono 
AND asistencia.estado = 'pendiente'
```

But always return duplicate result. result it´s correct, but i need that don´t duplicate it and i don´t know why.

[image: Result query]

attached my migration for you can show relations

**table user**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('nif');
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('direccion')->nullable();
        $table->string('perfil')->default('usuario');
        $table->integer('telefono')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**table bonos**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('bonos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('codBono');
        $table->string('tipo',20);
        $table->integer('minutos')->unsigned();
        $table->Double('precio',5,2);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**table asistencia**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('asistencia', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('codAsistencia');
        $table->dateTime('fecha');
        $table->longText('mensaje');
        $table->bigInteger('usuario')->unsigned();
        $table->string("estado", 20)->default("pendiente");
        $table->timestamps();



        // hacemos la insercción aquí ya que la tabla debe estar creada
        \DB::table('bonos')->insert([
            ['tipo' => '1/2H', 'minutos' => '30', 'precio' => '20'],
            ['tipo' => '1H', 'minutos' => '60', 'precio' => '40'],
            ['tipo' => '5H', 'minutos' => '300', 'precio' => '175'],
            ['tipo' => '10H', 'minutos' => '600', 'precio' => '330'],
            ['tipo' => '24H', 'minutos' => '1200', 'precio' => '600'],
        ]);



        $table->foreign('usuario')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

**table actuacion**

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('actuacion', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('codActuacion');
        $table->dateTime('fecha');
        $table->Integer('tiempoEmpleado');
        $table->Integer('asistencia')->unsigned();


        $table->foreign('asistencia')->references('codAsistencia')->on('asistencia');

    });
}
```

**table contratan**

```
public function up(){
    Schema::create('contratan', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('codContrato');
        $table->Integer('bono')->unsigned();
        $table->Integer('tiempoRestanteBono')->unsigned();
        $table->tinyInteger('activo')->default('0');
        $table->bigInteger('usuario')->unsigned();


        $table->foreign('usuario')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('bono')->references('codBono')->on('bonos');
    });
}
```

now you can see all my tables and his relations, but i don´t know why duplicate entries in my query...

I need get all assistances in state "pendiente"

Thanks so much for help

Comment: You need to add group by, you can add "group by asistencia.codAsistencia" to your query.

Comment: @BilhasryRamadhony in php my admin it´s ok, but to execute query in laravel, returned this: [previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 42000): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'bonosat.asistencia.fecha' isn't in GROUP BY at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bonosSat\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:331)

Comment: i can resolute, i go to database.php in config laravel and set to false "stric mode"

Comment: Actually better to use eloquent, instead of raw query like this. Please find in the laravel doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution, is add "group by" to query and in laravel, go to config/database and change this:

```
'strict' => false,
```

in strict, that it´s set in true, change to false

Answer (score 0):

You don't need group by, you only miss the condition between asistencia and contratan, so you match all records from asistencia to all records from contratan. Your result is not duplicated at all. Add the condition `AND contratan.usuario=users.id`.

Comment: thanks for your response, but i can´t see my query results.